# Additional brackets in Java8 stream map() function

Tags: java-8, java-stream

I'm working/testing streams in Java8 and come across very frustrating issue.
I've got the code which compiles well:

```
        List<String> words = Arrays.asList("Oracle", "Java", "Magazine");
    List<String> wordLengths = words.stream().map((x) -> x.toUpperCase())
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

And second one (nearly the same) which throw a warnings:

```
        List<String> words = Arrays.asList("Oracle", "Java", "Magazine");
    List<String> wordLengths = words.stream().map((x) -> {
        x.toUpperCase();
    }).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Warning:

```
The method map(Function<? super String,? extends R>) in the type Stream<String> is not applicable for the arguments ((<no type> x) -> {})
```

What does this additional brackets have changed?

Comment: If you are using the brackets and the return type of the lambda is not void, you have you to supply the `return` keyword in the lambda body (see also https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-LambdaBody)

Comment: that's not a `warning` but a compilation problem, *entirely* different things

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your lambda expression returns a value. If you use brackets you need to add a return statement to your lambda function:

```
List<String> words = Arrays.asList("Oracle", "Java", "Magazine");
List<String> wordLengths = words.stream().map((x) -> {
    return x.toUpperCase();
}).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Answer (score 3):

According to the official [Oracle tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/lambdaexpressions.html#syntax)

> A lambda expression consists of the following:
>
> A comma-separated list of formal parameters enclosed in parentheses.
>   The `CheckPerson.test` method contains one parameter, p, which
>   represents an instance of the `Person class`.
>
> Note: You can omit the data type of the parameters in a lambda
>   expression. In addition, you can omit the parentheses if there is only
>   one parameter. For example, the following lambda expression is also
>   valid:
>
> ```
> p -> p.getGender() == Person.Sex.MALE 
>     && p.getAge() >= 18
>     && p.getAge() <= 25
> ```
>
> The arrow token, `->`
>
> A body, which consists of a single expression or a statement block.
>   This example uses the following expression:
>
> ```
> p.getGender() == Person.Sex.MALE 
>     && p.getAge() >= 18
>     && p.getAge() <= 25
> ```
>
> If you specify a single expression, then the Java runtime evaluates
>   the expression and then returns its value. Alternatively, you can use
>   a return statement:
>
> ```
> p -> {
>     return p.getGender() == Person.Sex.MALE
>         && p.getAge() >= 18
>         && p.getAge() <= 25;
> }
> ```
>
> A return statement is not an expression; in a lambda expression, you
>   must enclose statements in braces (`{}`). However, you do not have to
>   enclose a void method invocation in braces. For example, the following
>   is a valid lambda expression:
>
> ```
> email -> System.out.println(email)
> ```

Since there is only one parameter in the provided lambda expression `(x) -> x.toUpperCase()` we can omit the parentheses: `x -> x.toUpperCase()`. `String#toUpperCase` returns a new `String` so there is no need to use `return` statement and braces. If instead we had a complex block with return statements we would have to enclose it into braces. Moreover in this case it is better to use [Method Reference](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/methodreferences.html) `String::toUpperCase`

```
List<String> wordLengths = words.stream().map(String::toUpperCase).collect(Collectors.toList());
```